# Google+ sign in for iOS (Apple mach-o linker error)

Tags: ios, google-plus

Good morning,

I'm trying to integrate the Google Plus login in my first iOS App and after following all the steps provided by Google in https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in I don't have any error in the code but it's something wrong when I compile the project:

I got 18 errors "Apple mach-o linker error" and I don't know why because I followed every step and everything seems correct.

Below you will find the error codes, I hope someone can help me with them because I don't know how to solve them.

```
      Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ALAssetsLibrary", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(NSData+GPPAdditions.o)
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(UIDevice+GPPAdditions.o)
  "_kABPersonFirstNameProperty", referenced from:
      ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
  "_ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople", referenced from:
      ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
  "_kABPersonEmailProperty", referenced from:
      ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
  "_ABAddressBookGetPersonCount", referenced from:
      ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
  "_ABPersonHasImageData", referenced from:
      ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
  "_ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat", referenced from:
      ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
  "_ABRecordCopyValue", referenced from:
      ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
  "_ABMultiValueGetCount", referenced from:
      ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
  "_ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions", referenced from:
      +[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:] in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
  "_ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex", referenced from:
      ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
  "_MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageKey", referenced from:
      -[GPPMediaPreviewView thumbnailImageRequestDidFinish:] in GooglePlus(GPPMediaPreviewView.o)
  "_MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification", referenced from:
      -[GPPMediaPreviewView initWithFrame:mediaAttachment:] in GooglePlus(GPPMediaPreviewView.o)
      -[GPPMediaPreviewView thumbnailImageRequestDidFinish:] in GooglePlus(GPPMediaPreviewView.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CMMotionManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPSpamSignal.o)
  "_ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion", referenced from:
      +[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:] in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
  "_kABPersonLastNameProperty", referenced from:
      ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMoviePlayerController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPMediaPreviewView.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: This library AssetsLibrary.framework in Step 3, is not included in your project, that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: Try cleaning your project using Command+Shift+K and adding the required frameworks again. Hope it will start working

Comment: not solve my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This library AssetsLibrary.framework in Step 3, is not included in your project, that's why you are getting this error.

Try these:

1. You need to add the AssetsLibrary framework to the “Link Binary With Libraries” build phase of your target.
2. Try cleaning your project using Command+Shift+K and adding the **required frameworks** again. Hope it will start working
3. Copy files into your project but forgot to check the target to add the files to. To resolve:
   Open the Build Phases for the correct target, expand Compile Sources and add the missing .m files.

Another cause, may be:

1. You include a static library that is built for another architecture like i386, the simulator on your host machine. To resolve:

If you have multiple library files from your libraries vendor to include in the project you need to include the one for the simulator (i386) and the one for the device (armv7 for example).

Comment: Love you man. (Dont get me wrong..lol..).. You saved me.. followed first 2 steps and it worked like charm... +1 for you